# C# Emulator 'To Many Connections'

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I have recently been receiving a mysql to many connectiions error, ive used sql queries such as the one below

`SET GLOBAL max_conmnections = 8000;` and ive also higherd the `mysql.pool.max to 8000` and when my emulator is in the debugger, it crashes on this void

```
private static SqlDatabaseClient CreateClient(int Id)
{
     MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection(GenerateConnectionString());
     Connection.Open();

     return new SqlDatabaseClient(Id, Connection);
}
```

the line thats highlighted that has caused it to crash was `connection.open();` it happens when i receive 10-12 online connections, the emulator was running for 7-8 hours in the debugger!

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is to close and dispose the connection and commands after used by the C# [**using**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement:

```
private static SqlDatabaseClient CreateClient(int Id)
{
    Int32 returnId = 0;

    try
    {
      using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GenerateConnectionString()))
      {
        connection.Open();

        if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
           returnId = Id;
        }

      }
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
       Console.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
           connection.Close();

        }
    }

    return returnId;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to say add that inside the sqldatabaseclient? that i posed, or add it above?

Comment: I updated the answer. If it was working previously but bomb because of not disposing the connections then the above might solve your problem

Comment: I'm asking where do i put this code? I'm a beginner to c# and im not sure where you mean to put this code? inside it above it?

Comment: I've tryed using the code you posted, the long one, and it errored, the Connetion.State lines errored and returnId erroredit says the name 'connection' doesnt exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rewrite into something like:

```
  private static void ExecuteInClientContext(int Id, Action<SqlDatabaseClient> callback) {
    if (callback == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");
    }

    using(MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection(GenerateConnectionString())) {
      Connection.Open();
      callback.Invoke(new SqlDatabaseClient(Id, Connection));
    }
  }

  static void Foo() {
    ExecuteInClientContext(1, (context) => {
      // whatever
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do i replace this code with my whole public static sq;databaaseclient? and will i need to code anything on the // whatever

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add codes like:
    `SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);`
then, after closing SqlDataReader's instance, the Connection object will also be closed.