# Too many connections error

Tags: c#, ado.net, mysql-connector

I've got an error in my C# application. I'm not sure if it's my program or my website. It's a gaming emulator and it says after 1-2 hours running 'Too many connections'. It also says it on my website.

The line this code is erroring on is below, and it errors and highlights the words `connection.Open();` when it crashes. I think it has something to do with not closing the connections.

//C# Coding (In VB)

```
private static SqlDatabaseClient CreateClient(int Id)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GenerateConnectionString());
    connection.Open();
    return new SqlDatabaseClient(Id, connection);
}
```

//Application error

```
[04:51] Exception - Session -> To many connection[]MySqlData.MySqlClient.MySqlPacket ReadPacket<> @ at MysqlData.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.Readpacket<>
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open<>
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open<>
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GtPooledConnection<>
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver<>
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection<>
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open<>
at Reality.Storage.SqlDatabaeManager.CreateClient in C:\iRP\SqlDatabaseClient.cs:line 24d
```

Comment: Do you close your db connections anywhere?

Comment: Are you closing those open Connections once you are through with them?  There is a limited amount of Connections you can have open.

Comment: I dont think there is anything that closes them no, i got this gaing cnsle application off a friend who coded it so i wouldnt know much about it

Comment: You need to close the connections once you are through otherwise they just stay open and when new ones are created your connection limits start to be reached till at some point you receive this error.

Comment: Next time please include the code and error yourself. There is absolutely no reason why you shouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: is there any coding i could add to close it? im begginer with c#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309362/c-sharp-emulator-to-many-connections or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318458/c-sharp-emulator-error-says-to-many-connections

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to place the code accessing your database within a using clause. By doing this you will ensure that your connections are disposed of when it is not used anymore.

Comment: is there any advice you can give to do this?

Comment: I would suggest the following

Comment: As they say there is 9 ways to skin a cat, I'm not sure of the layout and design of your project. I prefer to create a separate data access layer project using entity framework and the repository pattern to handle data access to the database. Within your individual repository classes you can place all your database code within using statements. If you post an example of the classes containing the code accessing the database we can perhaps help you with an example.

Answer (score 0):

[C# Too many connections in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255024/c-sharp-too-many-connections-in-mysql)

Take a look at that link. You need to use the 'using' statement so the connections are opened and closed properly.

Comment: I have used the using statment but im receiving a error when doing so